# App Engine dev server - Protocol wrong type for socket

Tags: sockets, google-app-engine, go, network-programming, cherrypy

I'm running an App Engine app written in Go locally with the development server and hitting the API with requests 1/s with roughly 100k-1MB JSON data.

From time to time the server prints an error trace but still continues to serve requests:

```
socket.error 41
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/foo/go_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 1302, in communicate
    req.respond()
  File "/Users/foo/go_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 831, in respond
    self.server.gateway(self).respond()
  File "/Users/foo/go_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 2127, in respond
    self.write(chunk)
  File "/Users/foo/go_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 2188, in write
    self.req.write(chunk)
  File "/Users/foo/go_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 879, in write
    self.conn.wfile.sendall(chunk)
  File "/Users/foo/go_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 970, in sendall
    bytes_sent = self.send(data)
  File "/Users/foo/go_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 977, in send
    bytes_sent = self._sock.send(data)
error: [Errno 41] Protocol wrong type for socket
```

The client is in a loop doing:

```
func call(url string, data []byte) error {
    r, err := http.Post(url, "application/json", bytes.NewReader(data))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer r.Body.Close()
    if r.StatusCode != http.StatusCreated {
        return fmt.Errorf("unexpected status code %d", r.StatusCode)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Golang App Engine SDK is now 1.9.26 and I had 1.9.25 before with the same issue.

I have unsuccessfully found anything online that would help me understand the issue.

Does anyone have an idea what this might be caused by?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an error bubbling-up from `wsgiserver2.py`'s use of python sockets, since many other references to "error 41" and "Protocol wrong type for socket" show up on the net as python `sockets` -module-related.

I think given the intermittent nature of this problem that it's likely an issue on the platform. In such a case, you should [file an issue report in the public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-appengine/issues/list) containing enough code to reproduce the issue, or an attached app which can reproduced the issue.

Best of luck in filing that issue report!